# Deal with assemblies references when using Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I use TFS 2010 and I'm having to change references of assemblies that I build from Debug to Release when I merge into the Main or Release branch.

When working on the Dev branch, I use the Debug assemblies, but I merge down to the Main or Release branch I need to manually change, and it's really time consuming.

Has anyone got best practices, or solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you refer to them using:

```
<Reference Include="Assembly">
  <HintPath>..\$(Configuration)\Assembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Then you dont need to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the assemblies are identical I suppose the only difference between a *.csproj in Dev & the same *.csproj in Main/Release would be something like:

```
<Reference Include="Assembly">
  <HintPath>..\Debug\Assembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

and then

```
<Reference Include="Assembly">
  <HintPath>..\Release\Assembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

As a first step, you could create a small console application that automates this with find & replace in all the project files involved. You could then run this app each time you do a merge.
The only thing you would need from TFS-SDk is the ability to checkout the *.csproj files.
(Another possible angle: Do you really need the Debug-version of the assembly in the DEV-branch?)

Comment: Yes we need the Debug version in the DEV branch, because we don't merge features until they are fully debugged, therefore these assemblies are not released. I would have though TFS would handle that situation, I thought it's pretty common for n-tier application and teram projects

Comment: I 'm not sure I follow.. Isolating implementation in your DEV-branch until certain quality criteria are met is indeed very common. How does switching between Debug/Release references in your *.csproj come into the picture? (in other words: why don't you reference the Release configuration in your DEV-branch?)

Comment: We have 3 branches Dev, Main and Release. When we work on Dev we reference the Debug config of each assembly. But when you merge down to Main and Release we switch to Release config, but the Project reference is still looking at the Dev branch assemblies, as Project file is versionned in TFS

Comment: OK, if you truly need the Debug config in DEV (I only asked WHY) you could proceed with the solution I 've provided, or any other answers you 'll might get.